# Changing :hover to :active for mobile touch devices

Tags: html, css

I want to use the `:hover` effect on desktop (which is working pretty fine) and switch to `:active` for mobile devices.

```css
.dropdown:hover,
.dropdown:active .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p id="dropdown-element">Dashboard öffnen</p>
    <p id="dropdown-element">Beratung beenden</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didnt work, but thanks anyways!

Comment: Its strange, what happens?

Comment: I dont remember anymore. I just ditched the whole thing, and used a JS solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can differentiate a CSS rule with the `@media` construct:

```
<style>
/* for all types */
.dropdown-content {
    ...
}
/* for desktop (also old ones) */
@media (min-width : 641px)
{
    .dropdown:hover {
        ...
    }
}
/* for smartphones */
@media (max-width : 640px)
{
    .dropdown:active {
        ...
    }
}
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
   <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p id="dropdown-element">Dashboard öffnen</p>
      <p id="dropdown-element">Beratung beenden</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Adjust `@media` `max-width` and `min-width` as your needs.